# How can I make the Roland D-20 sound like an ordinary piano?

Tags: synthesizer, piano

I just got this piano from a familymember, and I can't get it to sound like an ordinary piano? The sounds it makes are really wierd, like electronic and I just want to use for playing classical music. Thanks! :-)

Comment: You can take a look at the manual [here](http://media.rolandus.com/manuals/D-20_OM.pdf). They read kind of like the proverbial stereo instructions, but it may help steer you in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

First, the D-20 isn't a piano. It is a synthesizer, which is a type of instrument that allows you to create a wide variety of sounds. The good news is that the D-20 was intended for creating realistic instrument sounds rather than just sci-fi bleeps and bloops. The bad news is that by 2013 standards, the D-20 is going to sound a lot less realistic than contemporary high-resolution sample-based keyboards.

If there isn't a piano patch on your D-20 already, [then you may need to do a factory reset](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/how-do-i-reset-a-roland-d-20). According to page 263 of the PDF [manual](http://media.rolandus.com/manuals/D-20_OM.pdf), the first three patches will be acoustic pianos, followed by a honkey-tonk piano and some electric pianos.